# Is there support for encrypting the whole boot/system drive with Truecrypt in Ubuntu?

Tags: truecrypt

Is there (or is there not) support for encrypting the whole boot/system drive with Truecrypt in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The [full system encryption](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/system-encryption) support is currently only available for windows, take a look at [this answer on superusers](https://superuser.com/a/284176/115194).

If you are interested in a full encrypted linux system, you would have to use LUKS.

So to answer your question: no, it is currently not possible.